# Assembling a Haar-like filter for edge detection

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, convolution, edge-detection

In the paper located at this [link](http://www.google.ro/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcvl.ice.cycu.edu.tw%2Fmeeting%2F2010.11.16.pdf&ei=Ba-BVIrpF8ftaLDTgNAP&usg=AFQjCNF1-YDIOXn2-jQYQxYZnqS2p7OHxA&sig2=T79bg1lKRq1YtU5XiKg83w&bvm=bv.80642063,d.d2s) at "B. Detecting vertical edge using Haar-like feature" it mentions the use of a Haar-like kernel in order to obtain a resulting image 
which emphasizes vertical or horizontal edges in the input image the way the Sobel operator does. The way I understood the Haar features is that they output the difference of the sum of pixels from the white colored rectangles and the sum of pixels from the gray/black colored rectangle. I have trouble in determining the anchor point of the resulting Haar kernel (since the dimension mentioned in the paper is 6 x 6 ). My current understanding is that if I take the vertical edge mask mentioned in the paper the resulting 6 x 6 mask would be
  1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1
  1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1
  1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1
  1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1
  1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1
  1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1
[image: Vertical edge mask]

If anyone who is more knowledgeable about this can help me on this problem (how the kernel looks like and how would a convolution be perform in order to obtain an edge map imap) I would be very grateful.
Thank-you.

Comment: I think something is messed up here. Are you asking for the 'ancor point' of a general haar like feature? Or do you want to know which point the linked paper chose? The main problem is that haar like _features_ are features and not kernels. Therefore there is no general ancor point. How the linked paper did it can't be told as there is no code attached. Best bet is to ask the authors directly. As a side note: haar like features are binary. Meaning the feature is 1 if the difference is greater than some threshold and 0 otherwise.

Comment: I am asking how would a filter look like given its usage in the linked paper. Because it is a feature I have trouble imagining how it would be used as a filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information given in the paper [Vehicle Detection Method using Haar-like Feature on Real Time System](http://cvl.ice.cycu.edu.tw/meeting/2010.11.16.pdf) I can't tell how the group has done it exactly. However I can suggest a way on how this could be implemented.

The main difference between a haar-like feature and a convolution kernel is that the haar-like feature has a 'fixed position' within the image while a kernel is applied to each pixel.

A convolution kernel usually maps a local neighbourhood of a pixel to a value between 0-255. Haar-like features however define a mapping from the entire image to a single value. That is taking the sum of each pixel biased by -1, 0, 1. This bias is depending on the position of the pixel in the image.

#### Converting a convolution kernel into a set of features

That said we can extend a convolution kernel for a single pixel X and make it look similar to a haar-like feature by saying: We map the entire image by computing the sum of all pixels biased by what is given in the kernel for the neighbourhood of X and 0 else. If we do this for all pixels in the image we end up having width*height many features grouping them together in a large feature vector. Clearly they hold the same amount of information a convolution would have. However we loose the ability to easily access the 'origin' of a feature, meaning which pixel the kernel was attached to in order to compute this feature. This information is 'encoded' within the definition of that feature.

#### Converting a set of features into a convolution kernel

So can we reverse above process? For general features this can not be done. In case of the features given above we can take the non zero pixel values as the convolution kernel. If the feature set is chosen well we will end up having the same kernel for each feature. Then yes, we can get to a kernel from the feature set. Further we can find the 'origin' of the feature by averageing the position of each nonzero pixel in the feature's map.

In case of our haar-like features the answer is conveniently given in the paper. The convolution kernel is something of size 6 x 6 with the left half being 1 and the right half being -1, just as you suggested. (Top being 1 and bottom being -1 for the other mask.) Now the center of this 6 x 6 kernel would be 3.5 x 3.5 which is no pixel value.

Further the map defined as the kernel does not map into 0-255. This can be fixed by scaling the result or by applying a threshold. The second will loose some information, but probably provide more stable results.

The key question now is which features were chosen in order to optain the "haar-like feature edge" image seen in they're Fig. 5? In other words, at which positions does the kernel have to be evaluated? The best bet is to attach the kernel to every corner of 4 pixels in the image. This way a detected edge lives between pixels, which somehow makes sense as an edge is defined by the gradient between two (or more) pixels.
Note that the resulting image will have 1 row and 1 column less then the original image. However the resulting values are similar to boundaries and everything between two boundaries is 'the same object'.

Another way this can be done is to choose the (3,3) position of the kernel as the ancor point and attach this point to every pixel in the image just like eigenchris suggested. You could also choose (1,1) or any other point. However, as eigenchris mentioned, edges will appear off. So to make correct classification and to select the right regions of the original image you would have to account for the distance between the (true) center of the kernel and the one you chose.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from section 2 of reference [7] in this paper (https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~efros/courses/LBMV07/Papers/viola-cvpr-01.pdf):

> The value of a two-rectangle feature is the difference between the sum of the pixels within two rectangular regions.

So your interpretation of the kernel is correct. I can only assume they placed the anchor point at `(3,3)`, though this would result in the edges appearing slightly up and to the left of their "true" location.

Comment: I also consider your answer to correct but ended up accepting FirefoxMetzger's answer because of the trail of thought which may better help others arriving at this question. He also suggested the normalizing factor which I have forgot to add. In the end I obtained similar visual results as in the paper by applying the filter normalized by the kernel size.